# What to do or how to handle if health_status of a docker container changes

Tags: docker

I am running a docker container with health-cmd and I know it will turn to unhealthy when it stops working.

```
$ docker run 
 --name=some-container \
 --health-cmd='curl -sS http://127.0.0.1:5000 || exit 1' \
 --health-timeout=10s \
 --health-retries=3 \
 --health-interval=5s \
 --restart on-failure \
 container-image
```

I want to restart the container when it changes its health-status. How can do that? How to trigger the restart?

My Docker version 19.03.1, build 74b1e89

Comment: LinPy,  doesn't the -- restart works when the Container exit? I want to restart the container when the status turns unhealthy.

Comment: Okay, from the docker docs "on-failure - Restart only if the container exits with a non-zero exit status". So if the container exits with 1 then doesn't it auto restart because I set  --restart on-failure ? Please explain.

Comment: for every 35 seconds, will it exit?

Comment: Okay, and after that it restarts. Isn't it? please help me to understand

Comment: Thanks. Is it better to increase the health-interval ? What is the best way to handle?

Comment: I add all as an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

depends on your `Dockerfile` if the `health check` faild the container is exited with the code `1` becaus of your command :

```
--health-cmd='curl -sS http://127.0.0.1:5000 || exit 1'
```

therefore your restart policy `on-failure` will restart the `container` after ~35 seconds `timeout + retries + interval` when only the check failed.

the `timeout + retries + interval` values you can determind on many conditions there is no perfect values for them.

I think your command are good to go

Comment: If i set the --health-interval to 30m my container will run the check for every 30 min and will it be down for 30min 15 sec it the check fails?

Comment: your check will be done every 30 mins , so if it failed after 1 min then yes 30 min downtime

Answer (score 0):

You can use [autoheal](https://hub.docker.com/r/willfarrell/autoheal/) to restart unhealthy docker containers.
Sample:

```
docker run -d \
    --name autoheal \
    --restart=always \
    -e AUTOHEAL_CONTAINER_LABEL=all \
    -v /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock \
    willfarrell/autoheal
```

---

*Note: You must apply HEALTHCHECK to your docker images first. See https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#healthcheck for details.*